# JSF 2.0. Issues with .png

Tags: jsf-2

I am running into an issue trying to render.png image using jsf 2.0, where as JPG works fine

**h:graphicImage library="img" name="logo.png"**  --> Does not work, null pointer as shown below

**h:graphicImage library="img" name="logo.jpg**   --> No issues

---

**Update**
I see the following from Chrome Developer Tools console
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html

Not sure if I need to set the content type in web.xml

---

**resource structure**

WebContent/resources/img/logo.png

---

```
ErrorPageWrit E   An exception occurred
                                 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.setContentType(SRTServletResponse.java:1345)
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:333)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:183)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3935)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include your `resources` folder's structure?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.

Seems to be an issue with the mime mappings. For some reason png is not recognized by the server. Added mime mapping for png in web.xml

Using MyFaces Implementation, WAS7.

**Related post** : http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=19880.